# How do I access the "New Module" option in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, module

I'm attempting to follow [these instructions](https://developer.cardpointe.com/guides/android-sdk#importing-the-sdk-to-your-project) to integrate the Bolt Mobile SDK into my Flutter project, where step 5a is, after opening my project in Android Studio:

> Click File, select New, then select New Module.

However, I do not appear to have any such option:

[image: screenshot of the menu open with New highlighted]

Is there something I need to do to enable it? Was it moved somewhere else, or merged into another option (Import Module doesn't seem to cover it)? [The Android web site](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) confirms that it should be there, and that page was last updated 8 days ago as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the module into the main project than follow the instructions:

1. Move the module in your project directory.

Suppose if your module name is - library

2. In setting.gradle file add this lines

   `include ':library'`
3. In build.gradle file, inside the dependencies block add this lines

   `implementation project (':library')`

.........................................

Happy coding :)

Comment: There is no module yet, I'm trying to create one using the .aar file.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the instructions on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QVtE.png)
After that you will find multiple options, go to `new` and then at the top you will find `New Module` option. From there you can create new module or you can import, do as per your requirement.

Happy coding :)

Comment: [Not seeing it there either.](https://i.imgur.com/XHWzKOf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I give a solution for this issue,
Just follow my steps :

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsrXL.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCy3C.jpg)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTDzS.jpg)

Feel free to ask if any problem comes.

Happy coding :)

Comment: My UI looks completely different and I can't find an import package option anywhere https://i.imgur.com/CcX1z9q.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your flutter sdk set up because when you set up your flutter sdk it will be added automatically.

And If you done this.
Then check that did you add flutter plugin into android studio ? If not then follow this step.

1. Go to setings
2. Then search `plugin`
3. then search `flutter` into plugin
   section.
4. Then click on install on install button into flutter plugin
5. Then restart your android studio

I hope this problem will be solved because this is probable solution for this problem .

Thank you .

Comment: It's already installed, so that's not it either.

Answer (score 0):

**Workarounds**

Do one of the following:

- File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > Add (+)
- Try *Clean Project*, *Rebuild Project*, then *Invalidate Cache*
- Create a fresh project, check for *New Module...* menu option and if successful, move your files over.